# How to clone div blocks with varying colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a container with two color div blocks (one red and one green) and an image, these elements can be dragged and cloned into the drop zone. The image is cloned correctly, but I can make the code to accommodate with varying color blocks. I suppose I need to tweak the line `background-color:green;` under `.drag` to a variable, but not exactly sure how.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone', // allow to be dragged
        //cursor: 'move',
        //tolerance: 'fit'
    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                    ui.helper.remove();
                    x.draggable({
                        helper: 'original', // once inside drop zone, dragged again makes it move in there
                        containment: '#droppable', // once dragged in drop zone, it's contained there
                        tolerance: 'fit' //?
                    });
                    /* x.resizable({
                        maxHeight: 40,
                        minHeight: 40,
                        minWidth: 50
                    }); */
                    x.appendTo('#droppable'); // once dragged into drop zone, append it there
                }

                }
            });

});
```

```css
.col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid black;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color:green;
}

#droppable{
    width:500px;
    height :500px;
    border:2px solid black;
    }

#drag1{
    background-color:red;
}

#drag2{
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
           google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
           google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <div id="drag1" class="drag">
                </div>
                <div id="drag2" class="drag">
                </div>
                <img src='img_logo.gif' id="drag3" class="drag">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id ="droppable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have uploaded all the files (html, css, js) I need to run. The shown .js is the dragndrop.js script, and all the other script is connected online. The code can run on my computer, so I don't know why it produces error on stackoverflow.

Comment: Would something like this be what you are looking for? http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/07/drag-and-drop-jquery-with-clone-remove.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is simple. jQuery UI copies to clone only classes, not id, because it identifier can exist only once in DOM

so simply change drag1 and drag 2 to classes

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone', // allow to be dragged
        //cursor: 'move',
        //tolerance: 'fit'
    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                    ui.helper.remove();
                    x.draggable({
                        helper: 'original', // once inside drop zone, dragged again makes it move in there
                        containment: '#droppable', // once dragged in drop zone, it's contained there
                        tolerance: 'fit' //?
                    });
                    /* x.resizable({
                        maxHeight: 40,
                        minHeight: 40,
                        minWidth: 50
                    }); */
                    x.appendTo('#droppable'); // once dragged into drop zone, append it there
                }

                }
            });

});
```

```css
.col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid black;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color:green;
}

#droppable{
    width:500px;
    height :500px;
    border:2px solid black;
    }

.drag1{
    background-color:red;
}

.drag2{
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
     integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <div id="drag1" class="drag drag1">
                </div>
                <div id="drag2" class="drag drag2">
                </div>
                <img src='img_logo.gif' id="drag3" class="drag drag2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id ="droppable">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's assigned to elements must be unique, so the clone function doesn't copy the ID of the cloned to prevent that from hapenning. This prevents the style from being applied. I have changed your code by applying the colours as classes instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone', // allow to be dragged
        //cursor: 'move',
        //tolerance: 'fit'
    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                    ui.helper.remove();
                    x.draggable({
                        helper: 'original', // once inside drop zone, dragged again makes it move in there
                        containment: '#droppable', // once dragged in drop zone, it's contained there
                        tolerance: 'fit' //?
                    });
                    /* x.resizable({
                        maxHeight: 40,
                        minHeight: 40,
                        minWidth: 50
                    }); */
                    x.appendTo('#droppable'); // once dragged into drop zone, append it there
                }

                }
            });

});
```

```css
.col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid black;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color:green;
}

#droppable{
    width:500px;
    height :500px;
    border:2px solid black;
    }

.red {
    background-color:red;
}

.green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <div id="drag1" class="drag red">
                </div>
                <div id="drag2" class="drag green">
                </div>
                <img src='img_logo.gif' id="drag3" class="drag">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id ="droppable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```